# Split chained integer pairs

Tags: math, graph, integer

I have an array of integer pairs [a, b], e.g

```
[3, 7], [6, 7], [8, 5], [2, 6], [4, 2], [0, 5], [3, 4], [8, 1], [0, 1]
```

These pairs always form chains (closed loops), in this case, there are two
of them.

[image]

The problem is to split given array into n arrays for further graph
generation for every chain.

```
 [[3, 7], [6, 7], [2, 6], [4, 2], [3, 4]]
 [[8, 5], [0, 5], [8, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: Assuming that the chains are disjoint: say that `[a,b]` is related to `[c,d]` if the two sets `{a,b}` and `{c,d}` intersect. The transitive closure of this relation partitions the pairs in the way that you want. Use any standard algorithm for computing transitive closures.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/leprous/2pna1fpx/3/